# Widget overlap eachother in GridLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2, qgridlayout

I am trying to create a simple Program using `GridLayout`, all the widgets inside the `QWidget` window do show up and scale properly however the `LineEdit` overlaps the Title `Label` of the window.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class SimGrid(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimGrid, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My attempt at Grid Layout")
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        title = QtWidgets.QLabel("This is some big sample text to fill up")
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        success = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Success", self)
        cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel", self)

        grid.addWidget(title, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(text_edit, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(success, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(cancel, 4, 1)
        self.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2) you are using the following method:

> void QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget *widget, int fromRow, int
>   fromColumn, int rowSpan, int columnSpan, Qt::Alignment alignment =
>   ...)

The third and fourth parameters indicate the quantities and columns that will occupy, respectively, in your case the title will occupy 0 rows and 0 columns which is incorrect.

Using these criteria what you want is the following:

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class SimGrid(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimGrid, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My attempt at Grid Layout")
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        title = QtWidgets.QLabel("This is some big sample text to fill up")
        title.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        success = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Success", self)
        cancel = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Cancel", self)

        grid.addWidget(title, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(text_edit, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(success,2, 0, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(cancel,  2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = SimGrid()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: that worked, can you tell me why one of the buttons is bigger than the other? And the AlignCenter is not working either.